# npm install fails for react-native-button

Tags: node.js, react-native

I'm trying to install react-native-button.

I added the following code to the project package.json:

```
"react-native-button": "^1.3.1",
```

But for some reason, when running

```
npm install
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
> bable@1.0.1 install /Users/codeMonkey/Development/ReactNative/MaxApp/node_modules/bable
> echo "Did you mean to install the package `babel`?" && exit 1
```

Why do I get an error about bable? How is it related

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: can you please attach your full package.json ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why the issue happened but I found a solution:

I deleted the `node_modules` folder, ran `npm install` again and the issue was fixed.